# Wait until a webbrowser has loaded to preform code?

Tags: c#, browser

I have this code:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var webBrowsers = new [] { web1, web2, web3, web4 };
        for (int i = 0; i < webBrowsers.Length; i++)
        {
                status.Text = "Status: Creating account " + (on + 1).ToString();
                webBrowsers[i].Document.GetElementById("user[name]").SetAttribute("value", "Steven John");
                webBrowsers[i].Document.GetElementById("user[email]").SetAttribute("value", "StevenJohn" + on.ToString() + "@gmail.com");
                webBrowsers[i].Document.GetElementById("user[user_password]").SetAttribute("value", "froots2");
                webBrowsers[i].Document.GetElementById("user[screen_name]").SetAttribute("value", "StevenJohn" + on.ToString());
                webBrowsers[i].Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
                on += 1;
                acct = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\CMN573\twitter\made.txt");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\CMN573\twitter\made.txt", acct + Environment.NewLine + "stevenjohn" + on.ToString());
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\CMN573\twitter\number.txt", on.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I want to wait to execute the **entire** code until the page is done. The other questions I have found on here don't help me with this as it's kinda confusing as to where to put my code. I need to have it do it when I press the button.

Answer (score 0):

If got you,you want to register 4 account in a site,instead of using 4 web browser you can do this:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("To your register account url");
        }
        int on = 0;
        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (on <= 4)
            {
                //status.Text = "Status: Creating account " + (on + 1).ToString();
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user[name]").SetAttribute("value", "Steven John");
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user[email]").SetAttribute("value", "StevenJohn" + on.ToString() + "@gmail.com");
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user[user_password]").SetAttribute("value", "froots2");
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user[screen_name]").SetAttribute("value", "StevenJohn" + on.ToString());
                //Submit must be valid
                webBrowser1.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
                on += 1;
                string acct = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\CMN573\twitter\made.txt");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\CMN573\twitter\made.txt", acct + Environment.NewLine + "stevenjohn" + on.ToString());
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\CMN573\twitter\number.txt", on.ToString());
                //Navigate to url again
                webBrowser1.Navigate("To your register account url");
            }
```